# How to skip verification process for Google API Projects that works only in the sandbox mode?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-developers-console

Google started the OAuth developer verification process a few months back which forces the developers having OAuth applications to apply for verifications if they don't want their users to see a warning screen and to have an unlimited number of users using the OAuth flow.
I'm facing a problem due to this verification process when I have to use the projects in a local environment. There is no way I can verify the apps for local environments since the policies and T&Cs cannot be hosted.

Q1. Is there any way to skip the verification process and sandbox the OAuth application?
Q2. What is the exact limit for the accounts? (Since I use 5-10 Gmail accounts, but do multiple signups per day from those accounts and I still hit the limit quite often)

Answer (score 3):

> Q1. Is there any way to skip the verification process and sandbox the OAuth application?

If you check the side of the consent screen it answers some of your questions.

[image]

you can learn more [here](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en)

> Q2. What is the exact limit for the accounts? (Since I use 5-10 Gmail accounts, but do multiple signups per day from those accounts and I still hit the limit quite often)

If you add these accounts as users on the project in the developer console they should be able to use it while you are testing.

Comment: @DalmTo The users who are owners of the project (but not from same organization) still see the unverfied app screen.

Comment: everyone will see that it's unverified but those with access to the project should be able to use it is my understanding.    I can check into if you are having an issue

Comment: I have added a user **@gmail.com as the owner of my project. I need this Gmail account for testing but this account still sees unverified screen always. I've updated it about two weeks ago.